# IPフラグメントのDFフラグをONにする方法

Tags: android, network

IPヘッダにある、IPフラグメントの制御でDFフラグを常にONにしたいのですが
どのような方法が考えられるでしょうか？
OSはAndroidなのですが、カーネルの修正などが必要でしょうか？

Comment: 他に実現したいこと(何かを回避したい、等)があるように思いましたが、純粋にDFフラグを立てるのが目的でしょうか? (別のアプローチがあるかもと思い、コメントします)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。特定のシナリオは無く、セキュリティの指針としてIPフラグメントを使用しない方針に決まりましたので方法を探しおります。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `DF=1` でセキュリティが増すとも思えないうえに  TCP 通信が全滅しかねないのですが、なぜそんな判断に至ったのか興味があるような訊いてもしかたないような。

Comment: 外部ネットワークではなく、内部のネットワーク向けの設定となります。Ethernetでしか繋がらないので基本はMTUが同じでフラグメントが発生しないはず？なのにフラグメントが発生してるパケットは怪しいんじゃない？という感じかと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

机上確認の上での回答になりますが、
`sysctl.conf`に`net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc=2`を追加すれば、DFビットが立つようになると思います。

＃ただし、`sysctl.conf`を編集するにはroot権限が必要と思うので、簡単ではないように思います。